# Property 'tag' not found on object of type 'const _strong id'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I put `tag` on StoryBoard attribute inspector for my UILabel and I have this code on my ViewController.m :

```
for (id subview in [[self view] subviews]) 
{
    if (subview.tag==1) 
    {
        [subview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:12]];
    } else if (subview.tag==2) {
        [subview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:28]];
    }
}
```

when I run my code I got this error :

> Property 'tag' not found on object of type 'const _strong id'

what did I missed here? thank you......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
for (id subview in [[self view] subviews]) {
```

into

```
for (UIView *subview in [[self view] subviews]) {
```

The problem is the compiler has no idea what id actually is, so you cannot use . notation on it. If you want to keep up with id, cast it to a UIView using ((UIView*)id).tag

Answer (score 6):

While changing the type of `subview` from `id` to `UIView *` is the best option in this case, another viable solution would be to change:

```
if (subview.tag == 1)
```

to:

```
if ([subview tag] == 1)
```

Making a method call on an object of type `id` makes the compiler much happier than trying to access a property (despite them essentially being the same thing).

Answer (score 4):

"`id`" is like "`void *`" to the compiler. There are no declared methods or properties that it sees, hence the "`not found on object`" error you're seeing.

If you change that "`id`" in your "`for`" loop to "`UIView *`", you may have better results.